# How to install vscode for my another user in this computer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have already installed vscode in my main account. Then I created another new user in my computer, and I'd like to use vscode in this new user account. What should I do? Should I download and install vscode on this new user account again, or I can use a easier method?

I haven't tried anything